# PH - Free Radical - O2 confusion

Tags: organic-oxidation

some context 1st, this is my understanding:

I understand PH as the balance of protons vs electrons 7 being neutral, 1 being too many protons and 9 too many electrons.

A free radical in the body as a particle with excess protons (thus acid?)

O2 takes electrons from other molecules (I don’t know other mechanisms than having a + charge or excess of protons). Reason why the process of plucking electrons is called (misleadingly) oxidation, and why elements that donate electrons are called anti-oxidants.

### Confusion/contractions:

1. How then O2 “alkalinize the body”?
2. How ClO2 (Chlorine Dioxide) is an oxidant but donates 5 e-? (Donating is what antioxidants do?).

Comment: pH is a measure of the hydrogen ion (or hydronium in water) activity ($p\mathrm{H}=-\log(a_{\ce{H+}}$)),where activity approx equal concentration in dilute solutions.

Comment: There are some concepts you seem to have misunderstood. Your definitions of pH balance and free radicals for one are not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is often wrong.

$1$) The pH value is NOT a balance of protons vs. electrons. It is not a balance at all. It is the logarithm (or rather minus the logarithm) of the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ ions in solution : pH = - log [H+]

$2$) When pH = $1$, it does not mean that there are too many protons. There are never TOO MANY protons, whatever the solution. It only means that the concentration of the $\ce{H+}$ ions is $0.1$ M, since the logarithm of $0.1$ is $-1$.

$3$) When pH = $9$, it does not mean that there are too many electrons. There are never too many electrons, whatever the solution. And why choose pH = $9$ ? This value has no particular interest. pH = $9$ is obtained with a solution where the concentration of the ion $\ce{H+}$ is $\pu{10^{-9}}$ M, which also means that $\ce{[OH-]}$ = $\pu{10^{-5}}$ M.

$4$) A free radical is NOT a particle with excess protons. It is not an acid. A free radical has no excess at all, whatever the particle involved. A free radical in a group of atoms where a bond going to an outer atom has been broken in two equal parts, leaving one lonely electron on the atom belonging to the broken bond.

$5$) The oxygen molecule does not have an excess of protons. And elements that donate electrons are not called anti-oxidants. They are called reducers.

$6$) Oxygen does not alkalinize the body. Why the body ? $\ce{O2}$ never alkalinizes any substance, whatever this substance.

$7$) Why do you think that $\ce{ClO2}$ donates $5$ electrons ? And why $5$ ? $\ce{ClO2}$ does not donate electrons, as it is an oxidant.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, I think I was clear enough in that I had a few misunderstandings, and where they generated contradictions. Not sure why all the negatives, If I knew chemistry I wouldn't need to come here to ask in the 1st place. 
I'll leave this question undeleted (as suggested) because I don't care about me rep here, and I'm sure these are things many people are confused about, in the health space.
On (6) you are right, it's the removal of CO2 that does the trick.

Comment: (7) chlorine atom in chlorine dioxide has an oxidation number of +4. For this reason chlorine dioxide accepts 5 electrons when it is reduced to chloride. 
I had it backwards. reducing/accepting | oxidizing/donating are confusing terms.